# How to make function to return Observable?

Tags: angular, typescript, web, rxjs

I am new to rxjs library and struggle with some things related to the library.

I have function:

```
  initData(code)
  {  
    this.selectedLot = this.lots.find(x => x.id == code.Id);
    
    this.dataService.getplan(code.Id)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.plans = response.results;
        this.selectedPlan = this.plans.find(x => x.id == code.homeId);

      }) 
  }
```

As you can see the function contains service which makes http call and some selection by id from collection. The function initData needs to return Observable.

My question is how can I change the function above that it will return Observable?

### Update

I might have multiple http requests in initData function:

```
  initData(code)
  {  
    this.selectedLot = this.lots.find(x => x.id == code.Id);
    
    this.dataService.getplan(code.Id)
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.plans = response.results;
        this.selectedPlan = this.plans.find(x => x.id == code.homeId);
      }) 
       
       
       this.userService.getUserData(code.userId, code.placeId)
         .subscribe(resp=> { this.user = resp.results[0] });  

       this.userService.getAreaUrl(code.areaId)
         .subscribe(resp=> { this.areaLogoUrl = resp.results[0] });  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't subscribe to the observable, instead just return it

```
 initData(code) {  
    this.selectedLot = this.lots.find(x => x.id == code.Id);
    return this.dataService.getplan(code.Id);
 }
```

---

If you want to hit api's sequentially (from the comments) make use of [concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap) and [tap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/utility/do) operators.

```
initData(code) {

   return this.dataService.getplan(code.Id).pipe(
      concatMap(e => this.userService.getUserData(code.userId, code.placeId))
          .pipe(tap(resp => this.user = resp.results[0] )),
      concatMap(e => this.userService.getAreaUrl(code.areaId))
          .pipe(tap(resp => this.areaLogoUrl = resp.results[0] ))
   )

}
```

Comment: Nicolas, thanks for post. What if I will have few more observables in initData function?

Comment: Few more observables? Could you clarify that a bit with an example?

Comment: What exactly is the functionality you are trying to achieve here - Any particular reason you want to return 3 observables all at once?

Comment: yes, I have two functions initData and initSelectedData,  those function have to executed sequentially. I can can achieve it with help of pipe and switchMap operators:

this.initData(resp.Id, "").pipe(
  switchMap(() => this.initSelection(resp.results),
).subscribe(result => {
  console.log(result);
});

But I can use above mentioned operators only on Observables so this is the reason why I want to return Observables from mentioned functions.

Comment: Yes, you could use switchMap to achieve that functionality. If you want sequential execution use [concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap).

Comment: Nicolas, can you help me with that? in case if I have multiple services inside initData as described in update, how can I make function to return Observable?

Comment: I've updated the answer - I think this is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return the `Observable`. You can use `rxjs` operators to perform various transformation to the data

```typescript
 initData(code)
  {  
    this.selectedLot = this.lots.find(x => x.id == code.Id);
    
    return this.dataService.getplan(code.Id).pipe(
      tap(response => {
        this.plans = response.results;
        this.selectedPlan = this.plans.find(x => x.id == code.homeId);

      })
    ) 
  }
```